# How to remove embedded media content from the post content in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, video, types

I want to filter out only content from type post video, I've already separated out the embedded video, now I want only content to be filtered out.

```
// Only get video from the content if a playlist isn't present.
        if ( false === strpos( $content, 'wp-playlist-script' ) ) {
            $video = get_media_embedded_in_content( $content, array( 'video', 'object', 'embed', 'iframe' ) );
        }



        if (  is_single() ) {

            // If not a single post, highlight the video file.
            if ( ! empty( $video ) ) {
                echo '<div class="blog-img">';
                foreach ( $video as $video_html ) {
                    echo '<div class="entry-video">';
                        echo ($video_html);
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
            };

        };
```